# Why do multiple const declarations work inside a for...of loop?

Tags: javascript, constants, declaration, shadowing, for-of-loop

Working with a vanilla Javascript project, I stumbled upon a piece of code that declared multiple const inside a for...of loop. Trying to understand how it worked, I replicated it using an MDN example on the for...of docs:

```
const iterable = 'abc';

for (const value of iterable) {
  const iterableAgain = value + " Again!";
  console.log(iterableAgain);
  console.log(value);
}
```

...the code below will show:

```
a Again!
a
b Again!
b
c Again!
c
```

This means that **const is being re-declared each loop**. How is this possible? I thought **const** and **let** couldn't be redeclared without throwing TypeError, besides some circumstances. Is this a case of variable shadowing? If so, does that mean that every iteration in a **for...of** consist of a **different variable block**?

Note: Stack Overflow threw me similar questions that have been asked, but to clarify, *none* have been made related plain Javascript, all of those have been asked related to Typescript.

Comment: "*This means that const is being re-declared each loop*" it's not **re-**declared. It's just a different const binding each loop.

Comment: That's how block scope works, the variable is unique for every round, i.e. it's re-created, not re-assigned.

Comment: That's the part I don't get: Why is it able to use the exact same name on each loop? If it was outside a loop, it woud throw an "error: unknown: Identifier 'iterableAgain' has already been declared". 

Edit for Teemu's comment: Does that mean that each "for...of" iteration is its own scope?

Comment: Because Javascript specifically allows for this as sort of a special case, since it makes a lot of sense and solves a number of common problems.

Comment: Every round of the loop is executed in its own scope, that's what we call "block scope", and that's why you can use `const` to declare the variable.

Comment: This will help you a lot to understand whats going on: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript

Comment: @KaiLehmann I don't think the article addresses the scenario shown here.